# How can I bind a parameter in sqlsrv_prepare?

Tags: php, sql-server

We have this stored procedure which created by the other guiys

```
    DECLARE @RC int
DECLARE @Number varchar(10)

-- TODO: Set parameter values here.

EXECUTE @RC = [dbo].[spWebGetPrice] 
   @Number
GO
```

My question is how can I bind a value on @Number using sqlsrv_prepare.

I am using this code but it says that the parameter is still not supplied

```
$sql = sqlsrv_prepare($conn,"spWebGetPrice", ['@Number', 123456]);
```

Comment: When you read the [documetation](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php) what didn't you understand? Then we can try to elaborate

Comment: The thing that isn't clear is how can I bind a value on parameters like `@Number`

Comment: You need to use parameter markers (`?`). There's an example on the page that demonstrates how to execute a procedure called `stp_Create_Item`; what wasn't clear in that one?

Comment: There's even some comment which explains it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.sqlsrv-prepare.php#115353

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Procedure *arguments* are separate from prepared query *placeholders*.

`sqlsrv_prepare` expects as its second argument a *full string of SQL*, with `?` in place of data which will be supplied as separate parameters. This is easier to illustrate with a plain select query:

```
sqlsrv_prepare($conn, 'Select * From Users Where Username=?', [$username]);
```

To run a stored procedure, you need to do the same thing - write out the SQL with `?` placeholders:

```
sqlsrv_prepare($conn, 'Exec spWebGetPrice @Number=?', [123456]);
```

Comment: Thank you for the response I really appreciate it. This is really pretty straight forward as I am new with this kind of approach.